# Appending to existing avro file in HDFS with NiFi

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-nifi, avro

I have this NiFi flow that grabs events in JSON from a MQTT broker, groups them according to some criteria, transforms them to Avro rows, and should ouput them through files in a Hadoop cluster.

I chose Avro as the storage format since it's able to append new data to an existing file.

These events are grouped by source, and ideally I should have one separate Avro file in HDFS for each event source, so NiFi accumulates new events in each file as they appear (with proper write batching of course since issuing a write per new event wouldn't be very good, I've already worked this out with a MergeContent processor).

I have the flow worked out but I found out that the last step, a PutHDFS processor, is file format agnostic, that is, it doesn't understands how to append to an existing Avro file.

I've found [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/nifi/pull/1716/files) that implements exactly that, but it was never merged into NiFi due various concerns.

Is there a way to do this with existing NiFi processors? Or do I have to roll out my custom PutHDFS processor that understands how to append to existing Avro files?